# Why Android class is equal but values in class is not equal?

Tags: java, android

```
package com.custom.wangzhi.myapp;

import android.util.Log;

public class TestUtil {
    public void print(Class clazz, int t) {
        try {
            Log.i("print 1 ", "result  " + R.layout.class.equals(clazz)
                    + "  " +       R.layout.class.getClassLoader().equals(clazz.getClassLoader())
            );
            Log.i("print 2 ", R.layout.act1 + "  " +     clazz.getDeclaredField("act1").get(null)+"  "+t);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}


package com.custom.wangzhi.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity1 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.latzc1);


        Log.i("MainActivity1", "wangzhi app       " + R.layout.act1);
        new TestUtil().print(R.layout.class, R.layout.act1);

}



Log: 

11-26 10:07:23.097 7999-7999/com.custom.dynamic.layoutcastdemo I/MainActivity1: wangzhi app       2130968577
11-26 10:07:23.097 7999-7999/com.custom.dynamic.layoutcastdemo I/print1 : result  true   true    
11-26 10:07:23.097 7999-7999/com.custom.dynamic.layoutcastdemo I/print2 : 2130968576  2130968577  2130968577
```

**MainActivity1 is a library module**

**if i run by the default in android studio is ok ,but when i use   [layoutcast](https://github.com/mmin18/LayoutCast) (i do some change in this )  run,then print log in above**

what layoutcast do: 

1.it will find the code  which is changed(compare the "projectdir/build/outputs/**.apk" 's time )
  
2.use aapt package all resource to  generate a res.zip and R.java
  3.use javac,dex all changed java file to generate a dex 
 4.then translate the res.zip and dex to android phone, 
5. use DexClassloader load the dex and generate a new Resource which add res.zip to replace the system Resource .
6.finally ,reboot the application.
 my english is poor ,and first ask in stackoverflow,so if anyone don't know my mean ,please contact me . thanks very much

Comment: Please change your Log.i tags to "wangzhi1", "wangzhi2", "wangzhi3", "wangzhi4" because it's hard to understand.

Comment: @Gi0rgi0s thanks for your advice，the question have been changed

Comment: The log output cannot come from this program. Three booleans are shown but only two are printed.

Comment: @Henry  sorry,it is my fault  when i copy the code and log to the stackoverflow, i have fix that